# Ruby on Rails' respond_to causing strange error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mime-types, respond-to

There is another `respond_to` for the usual case, and a special case when a `param[:top]` is passed in, so there is another `respond_to` earlier in the code:

```
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render :top_page_analytics }
        format.json { render :json => @analytics }
        format.xml { render :xml => @analytics }
        return
      end
```

but the above code actually gave a strange error for missing template for json, and further debug leading to:

```
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render :top_page_analytics }
        format.json { render :json => @analytics }
        format.xml { render :xml => @analytics }
      end
      return
```

which fixes the bug.  The return is needed so that there will be no "double render error" because the program will flow to the other `respond_to`.  But I wonder the strange syntax of `respond_to`, looking somewhat like a case statement, may cause error like that at the top?

Answer (score 1):

The return can't go there because you're passing a block. The block isn't executed in the immediate context of the controller action. When you return from the block, you're actually returning from the function yielding (respond_to), not the controller action.