# ActionController::UnknownFormat when add respond_to

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5.2

When I remove `respond_to` and `render to view`, everything works fine but adding the `js render` gives an error.

controller code :

```
if params[:stock].present?
  @data = params[:stock]
  @stock = Stock.new_form_lookup(params[:stock])
  respond_to do | format |
      format.js  {render partial: 'user/result'} 
  end
else
  flash[:danger] = "no search found "
  redirect_to my_portfolio_path
end
```

end

View code:

```
<%= form_tag searchstock_path , remote: true , method: :get, id:"stock-search" do %>
```

application.js code:

```
//= rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: can you add the error, please

Comment: And you might take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3730812/8685260

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a file with `controller_action_name.js.erb` in the view and render the partial their.

```
$('.className').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'user/result') %>")
```